# LinkedIn V2 api full profile

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I am using linked in V1 api to fetch information about the authenticated user. my app have r_fullprofile permission.

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url,pictureUrls::(original),email-address,public-profile-url,industry,summary,specialties,phone-numbers,main-address,location:(name,country:(code)),positions:(id,title,summary,start-date,end-date,is-current,company:(id,name,type,size,industry,ticker)),educations:(id,school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities,notes,grade),associations,interests,num-recommenders,date-of-birth,publications:(id,title,publisher:(name),authors:(id,name,person),date,url,summary),patents:(id,title,summary,number,status:(id,name),office:(name),inventors:(id,name,person),date,url),languages:(id,language:(name),proficiency:(level,name)),skills:(id,skill:(name)),certifications:(id,name,authority:(name),number,start-date,end-date),courses:(id,name,number,occupation),recommendations-received:(id,recommendation-type,recommendation-text,recommender),honors-awards,three-current-positions,three-past-positions,volunteer).

Now, i am migrating to V2 API i cannot able to fetch all profile information.

when i make request to https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me

I get very few information like FirstName, LastName, profilePicture,id

I also tried to get information using

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?fields=id,firstName,lastName,email-address

with above endpoint can able to access id,firstname and lastname not email.

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,skills) -with this endpoint i can access id,firstname and lastname, not skills

Answer (score 2):

LinkedIn's v2 APIs return a reduced "Lite" Profile by default. Access to the Full Profile requires a Partnership with LinkedIn.

> This API will only recognize a new “Lite Profile” permission, which supports a reduced set of member profile fields. See the documentation for more details.

source: https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates